# How to not increase displaying p element

Tags: javascript, css

request:
when every color changes,the html will show

```
linear-gradient(to right,rgb(x,x,x),rgb(x,x,x))
```

But my code will show up every times when color changes.

I need to not show up every time and just change the rgb's value

Is there improve ways to show linear-gradient?

in my js:

```
   var css = document.querySelector("h3");
   var color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
   var color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");
   var body = document.getElementById("gradient");

   function setGradient() {
    body.style.background = 
    "linear-gradient(to right, " 
    + color1.value 
    + ", " 
    + color2.value 
    + ")";

    css.textContent = body.style.background + ";";
   }

   //set initial value in the first load page
   setGradient();

   //display linear gradient value
   body.addEventListener("input",function(){
    var p = document.createElement("p")     
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("linear-gradient(to right,"+ 
    color1.value+ ","+ color2.value+ ")"));
    body.appendChild(p);
    })

    color1.addEventListener("input", setGradient);

    color2.addEventListener("input", setGradient);
```

in my html:

```
       <h1>Background Generator</h1>
       <input class="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#00ff00">
       <input class="color2" type="color" name="color2" value="#ff0000">
       <h2>Current CSS Background</h2>
```

in my CSS:

```
    body {
        font: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: .5em;
        top: 15%;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow); /* Standard 
        syntax */
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you do it, using `document.querySelectorAll`, then bind event listener of `change`. Take notice that `css.textContent = body.style.background + ";";`  is set after `setGradient()` and inside `change` event listener

```js
 var css = document.querySelector("h3");
   var color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
   var color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");
   var body = document.getElementById("gradient");
  
   function setGradient() {
    body.style.background = 
    "linear-gradient(to right, " 
    + color1.value 
    + ", " 
    + color2.value 
    + ")";
   
  
   }

   //set initial value in the first load page
   setGradient();
  css.textContent = body.style.background + ";";//for first initialization
   //display linear gradient value
   var elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll('.color1, .color2');//store the input to var

    elementsArray.forEach(function(elem) {//iterate it, and bind change event listener for each
        elem.addEventListener("change",function(){
            css.textContent = body.style.background + ";";
         })
    });
 

    color1.addEventListener("input", setGradient);

    color2.addEventListener("input", setGradient);
```

```css
  body {
        font: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: .5em;
        top: 15%;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow); /* Standard 
        syntax */
       }
```

```html
 <body id="gradient">
    <h1>Background Generator</h1>
       <input class="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#00ff00">
       <input class="color2" type="color" name="color2" value="#ff0000">
       <h2>Current CSS Background</h2>
<h3>
</h3>
  </body>
```

Comment: sorry,your linear gradient still increase every time when click the color. So i can't choose you for the answer at this moment –

Comment: @Jacky Okay code snippet updated, now the `<h3>` changes the same like `<p>`

Comment: Could you look at snippet? every time i choose the color picker and choose one color,then your linear gradient still increase like: LINEAR-GRADIENT(TO RIGHT, RGB(146, 186, 69), RGB(255, 0, 0));LINEAR-GRADIENT(TO RIGHT,#3E36C9,,#FF0000) i don't want linear gradient to increase when i choose the color picker.I just want one linear gradient to show and  only rgb's value to change.Like before changes: Linear gradient  RGB(146, 186, 69), RGB(255, 0, 0)); after change(no increase):Linear gradient RGB(62,54,201)RGB(255,0,0)

Comment: So dont append the `<p>` elmeent you mean? Code updated, can you take a look again?

Comment: Thanks.This is what i want.What is elem in the code mean?

Comment: @Jacky `elem` is just a parameter returned from `.forEach()` method.
Since we use `elementsArray.forEach`, the `elem` is HTMLElement for `.color1` and `.color2`